# Desenvolver uma Tela igual a Tela de Recebimento de SMS (android). Usuario receber Mensagens

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa Tarde,

Estou iniciando em Android.

Estou fazendo um **app** onde que um usuario vai receber varias mensagens de outros usuarios, cada mensagem contendo 2 campos.

O usuario vai acessar uma Tela e ver essa mensagens.

Gostaria de fazer essa Tela com o mesmo layout de quando recebemos um **SMS**, conforme abaixo:

**Alguem pode me indicar onde encontro esse Layout ? Ou como posso fazer ?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tutorial explicando como customizar uma **ListView** http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thiago, da pra usar isso dinamicamente, ou seja, conforme os usuarios enviar mensagens, eu adiciono ?

Comment: Sim! Você deve ter um Serviço que irá receber / ler os SMS, e este deve notificar sua tela, que por sua vez adiciona a lista através do ArrayAdapter!

Comment: Ok, agora que voce me informou qual componente utilizar... eu pesquisei e encontrei esse tutorial tbm :https://arthurlehdermann.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/android-criando-um-listview-personalizado/     ... Entao, não é SMS, vão ser dados que eu vou pegar de um WS externo, e mostrar pro Usuario....to usando retrofit + php slim...

Comment: Ok, se quiser criar uma resposta para eu positivar... Oobrigado